# How to check skype login existence?

Tags: authentication, skype

Well. I'd like to check any skype login existence in some way (not trying to register), but don't know how to do it at all.

Does somebody know the answer?

Comment: You could do this through the Skype API, I believe. [See this thread](http://community.skype.com/t5/Desktop-API-former-Public-API/Adding-Contact-through-Skype4Py/td-p/197510)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SkypeKit](http://developer.skype.com) and its API for C++ / Java / C# / Python. Java has [ContactSearch](http://developer.skype.com/skypekit/reference/java/html/com/skype/api/ContactSearch.html) class for example.